# How do you get data on other countries' stock prices?

Tags: curated-data

```
FinancialData["TSLA", {{2016, 1, 1}, {2022, 1, 31}}, "Value"]
```

Can financial data search only for data on U.S. stock prices?
How do you get data on other countries' stock prices?
For example, I want to bring up the stock price for a specific Korean company "SAMSUNG" as above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can show foreign stocks, you have to find the correct index, and it will be in the original currency. For SAMSUNG, I found the index on Yahoo:

`DateListPlot[FinancialData["005930.KS", "Jan. 1, 2000"]]`

[image]

and just to make sure:

```
FinancialData["005930.KS", "Name"]
```

returns the name:

> "Samsung Electronics Co Ltd"

Comment: Thank you. Be happy!!